# Бесконечно зациклился while и if в Python

Tags: python, циклы, if, while

```
word = 'zato' 
x = len(word) 
newWord = [] 
indexOfList = 0 
standartCharsList = ['a','o','t','z'] 
replaceCharsList = ['4','0','7','2'] 

for char in word: 
    while indexOfList < x: 
        if char == standartCharsList[indexOfList]: 
            newWord.append(char.replace(char,replaceCharsList[indexOfList])) 
            indexOfList += 1 
print(newWord)
```

Хочу чтобы слово заменялось с стандартных(standartCharsList) символов на новые(replaceCharsList)
В итоге,он зацикливается на цикле while и if.
Подскажите пожалуйста,почему так происходит?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в отступах, у вас получается что символ из `standartCharsList` переходит на следующий, только если он совпадёт с char и очевидно это не всегда возможно

```
indexOfList = 0
while indexOfList < x: 
    if char == standartCharsList[indexOfList]: 
        newWord.append(char.replace(char,replaceCharsList[indexOfList])) 
    indexOfList += 1
```

Comment: Спасибо,это сработало. Хотелось бы задать еще один вопрос,после всех итераций, лист newWord возвращает только 2,т.е z. Как я понимаю,он заменил только первую букву из word,и все остальные пропустил. Как сделать так,что бы он проверял каждую букву отдельно? Я для этого сделал цикл for,но,он почему то не работает как я думал.

Comment: только что запустил, всё работает, может вы убрали отступ в for?

Answer (score 1):

На первой итерации списка сравнивается `char` ('z') с нулевым элементом `standartCharsList` ('a'), условие не выполняется и цикл переходит к следующей итерации, без выполнения инструкции

```
indexOfList += 1
```

так же находящейся под условием. На следующих итерациях происходит ровно то же самое.